# What is the meaning of update-alternatives --config java command

Tags: java, version

The + was my selection, what does * mean?

```
 [root ~]$ update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 programs which provide 'javac'.
  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
 + 1           /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/javac
*  2           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64/bin/javac
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asterisk identifies the default entry, *i.e.* the alternative which would be used in automatic mode:

```
update-alternatives --auto javac
```

This doesn't appear to be mentioned in the manpage, but see [the source code](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/chkconfig.git/tree/alternatives.c#n796): `+` indicates the current selection, `*` the "best" selection.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the source code. Can I remove the * entry java-1.7.0 ?

Comment: You'd need to uninstall the OpenJDK package; if nothing depends on it you should be OK.